# Can't loop through 2D array using 'rows' in JS or TS

Tags: javascript, typescript, multidimensional-array

Suppose, I want to create a 2D array of the following structure:

```
[0, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0]
```

For achieving my goal, at first, I created a 2D array with initial values of `0`:

```js
function createGrid(m: number, n: number): number {
    let grid: number[][] = new Array(m).fill(0).map(() => new Array(n).fill(0));

    return 0;
};
```

Then, I changed the values of the first row (except `grid[0][0]`) to `1`:

```js
function uniquePaths(m: number, n: number): number {
    let grid: number[][] = new Array(m).fill(0).map(() => new Array(n).fill(0));

    for (let i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
        grid[0][i] = 1;
    }

    return 0;
};
```

Similarly, I tried to change the values of the first column (except `grid[0][0]`) to `1`:

```js
function uniquePaths(m: number, n: number): number {
    let grid: number[][] = new Array(m).fill(0).map(() => new Array(n).fill(0));

    for (let i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
        grid[0][i] = 1;
    }

    for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        grid[i][0] = 1;   // <<-- 'Throws error here`
    }

    return 0;
};
```

But, it throws the following error:

```
grid[i] is undefined
```

Can someone please explain what I'm missing here?

[TypeScript Playground Code Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABOGBHEBTACgQygCwGcAKAWwC5EwRSAjDAJwBorLq7GBKNm+hxAN4AoRKMQAbDFEQBzBjAAmPDgwDaAXQ2IAvFQwB3RAEEGDHAE8ynAHTAY48cQAMN0jgAOxYpx0A+PYYmZpZgNnYOzpycANxCImLAcPzEktIwOogAjNGI6QA8uqQ5MADUJT7CYlWy8gqqTpow6hnZ8aIAvnFVicmpuS3FiAVUxWUVbdVyiqpN9c26rVWdExAIhHCS1uJwMsRTCjFdYgxSIAxITrHtsUIo6Nh4RMQAzCwALDFAA)

Comment: Looks like you've swapped your `m` and `n` loops. Your outer array is declared to be of size `m` (`new Array(m).fill(0).map(...`) but you're looping over the outer indexes from 1 to `n`. Ditto & vice versa for the inner indices.

Comment: `for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {` because arrays are zero index, they do not start at 1

Comment: based on your logic 'n' cannot be bigger then 'm'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is two errors:

- You swapped `m` and `n` when you wanted to fill with `1`.
- You created overflow with condition `i <=`, you needed `i <`.

Corrected version:

```js
function uniquePaths(m: number, n: number): number {
    let grid: number[][] = new Array(m).fill(0).map(() => new Array(n).fill(0));

    for (let i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        grid[0][i] = 1;
    }

    for (let i = 1; i < m; i++) {
        grid[i][0] = 1;
    }

    console.log(grid);

    return 0;
};

uniquePaths(3, 4);
```

Result:

```
[[0, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check the indices and check the logical not value and return a number of the check.

```js
function createGrid(m, n) {
    return Array.from(
        { length: m },
        (_, i) => Array.from(
            { length: n },
            (_, j) => +(!i !== !j)
        )
    );
};

createGrid(3, 4).map(a => console.log(...a))
```